# MailApp.SendEmail script for multiple tabs

Tags: google-apps-script

I have been looking how to write the script to check and run on multiple tabs. What I have now, I would need to copy/paste and set execution triggers one by one.

Script I have:

```
function SendEmail() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("1");
  var value = sheet.getRange("F3").getValue();
  var subject = "subject";
  var message = "message";

  if (value >0){      
    MailApp.sendEmail("email", subject, message);
  }
}
```

I have this running every 8 hours (trigger run).

I am looking to add more tabs so that for each tab the script can check and send an email if the value of individual tabs is more than 0.

Any ideas on how to do this?

The value in every tab is under F3. Tab names, for example, 1,2,3,4...

Thank you!!!

Comment: I'm not going to lie, I have no idea the problem you are trying to solve. When you say tabs do you mean any open tabs? Or do you just mean the one running the webapp. What is the point of the script you are creating in the first place. It might help find the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do what you looking for if I understood the issue correctly.

```
function SendEmail() {
  //Get the Spreadsheet
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  //Get all Sheets in the Spreadsheet
  var sheets = ss.getSheets();

  //Create a variable for the email address, subject and message
  var email = "";
  var subject = "";
  var message = "";

  //Can change the starting sheet by changing the value of "i" - 0 will be the first sheet.
  for (var i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++){

  var sheet = sheets[i];
  var value = sheet.getRange("F3").getValue();

  switch(sheet.getSheetName) {
    case "Sheet1":
       email = "email1@domain.com";
        break;
    case "Sheet2":
        email = "email2@domain.com";
        break;
    default:
        value = 1
        email = "yourEmailAddress@domain.com";
        subject = "Message Failed to Send";
        message = "There was an error sending email, please investigate";
}

  if (value >0){      
    MailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, message);

}//END OF IF STATEMENT
}//END OF FOR LOOP
}//END OF FUNCTION
```

Comment: Thank you, @New_2_Code. I see some people didn't understand correctly. Just to clarify: This script will check all tabs, for example I have tab called 1, 2 ,3. So it will check if in each of the tabs, F3 has more than 0, then it will send email, right?

Comment: What if I want to send email to different emails, for example, if tab 1 F3 value is >0 than send email to 1@gmail.com. If tab 2 F3 value >0 then send email to 2@gmail.com. I hope it is clear. Thank you everyone!

Comment: Hi David, I updated my answer. I used a switch statement which will change the email address based on the sheet name. I added some reporting in the default catch in case the sheet name does not exist. Note this method will require you to hard code the sheet names into your code.

Comment: For some more info on switch statements check here: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp

Comment: Hi New_2_Code, not really. This script doesn't check every sheet. I need something that it checks every sheet individually and if F3 on any of the sheets is higher than 0 than send email to specific email.

Comment: Hi David, this does check every sheet. The switch statement checks the name of the sheet. If the name of the sheet meets certain criteria it will set the email variable. You will need to edit the switch statement to meet your own requirements. (This was done based on your comment.)